# Using MSAL to access Azure AC with implicit grant

Tags: azure-ad-msal

How can I use MSAL to access Microsoft Graph using Azure AD with implicit grant?

I've got Azure registered application with `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` enabled and I'm trying to call `userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent` but I keep getting an error "User login is required".

I'm calling it from Sharepoint online app, so I'm already logged in to 365 services.

Is there any sample for such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-graphapi-v2) is a sample of how to use MSAL with Azure AD to call the Microsoft Graph (includes Sharepoint, Exchange, and several other workloads). To checkout how to do this, checkout the [MS Graph Docs](https://graph.microsoft.io).

The error you're getting is caused by using `acquireTokenSilent` without a signed in user. MSAL has two primary functions: `acquireTokenSilent` and `acquireToken`.  The former is a guaranteed silent request (will never show a sign in page to the user), and will fail if it cannot do this successfully. The latter will always show a sign in page to get new tokens for a user.

The pattern recommended is to attempt an `acquireTokenSilent` function call, and then upon failure attempt an `acquireToken`.  This avoids unnecessary sign ins, but also doesn't get your app in a state where it cannot perform authenticated operations.

Comment: I forgot to add, as you're using MSAL which means you're hitting the Azure AD v2 endpoint.  Make sure your app is registered in the [App Reg Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) rather than the Azure Portal. You'll also need to set `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` to true here as well.